# Changing the laucher activity in Android app updated version

Tags: android, launcher

I am adding a splash screen as lauch activity in a app which already in the market. When I install the new build in the device (LG Optimus p350)which is already has the previous application, I can not install the new build. Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: you can uninstall the previous build and then try to install the new build

Comment: When i uninstalled the prev application its working. But what is the issue the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both applications'

- package have same name.
- APK was signed with same keystore.

Comment: both has same keystore and package name

Comment: so how are you pushing the apk to device, using eclipse or using terminal?

Comment: Currently I have put new signed apk in the sdcard and installed from there for testing purpose. In the app I have a version upgrade api, in which new apk is downloaded from the server and installed from the code.

Comment: Is there is any way to uninstall the app and reinstall the updated app from the code??